# AtTask API - 403 Forbidden

Tags: attask

We are trying to access the AtTask API from our cloud integration service. We are getting a 403 Forbidden error when sending requests from the cloud. When sending requests from our own domain it works. Is there some way to allow our cloud server to interact with the API or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as long as your cloud service can communicate with workfront. This error indicates that your system is blocking the request.